# How to select only column with not null values

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to list columns only with not null values.

I created a view to count columns where I am counting number of such a columns:

```sql
nvl2(q1,1,0)+nvl2(q2,1,0)+nvl2(q3,1,0)+nvl2(q4,1,0)+nvl2(q5,1,0)+nvl2(q6,1,0)+nvl2(q7,1,0)+nvl2(q8,1,0)+nvl2(q9,1,0)+nvl2(q10,1,0) cnt_col
```

I am trying to figure out how to use that view with select statment. Oracle won't let me do sth like this:

```sql
case when cnt_col = then q1 when cnt_col = 2 then q1,q2 when cnt_col = 3 then q1,q2,q3 ...
```

Is it possible to do that with SQL?

Comment: Please share desired output.

Comment: The number of columns has to be known when the statement is parsed, i.e. before those counts are known. So no, you can't do that as part of a SQL query; unless you use dynamic SQL. This might be something you want a reporting or application layer to handle though. (Which could potentially be a fudge in your client/IDE - depends how and where you'll run the query.)

Comment: generally i would like to only list columns with values, when whole column is null it should not be visible.

Comment: Do not mix presentation task and data processing task. Process this on your application side, because in SQL columns should be known at the execution time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear exactly what output you're expecting. But if you want to have a where clause/select list that matches the number of columns in the table, either you need to:

- Use dynamic SQL to construct the query
- Use [SQL macros](https://blogs.oracle.com/datawarehousing/sql-macros-have-arrived-in-autonomous-database) in 19.6 and up

Here's an example using SQL macros. Pass it a table (note this can be a named subquery or view as well as a real table) and it generates a query returning all the rows where all columns are non-null:

```
create or replace function nn_rows (
  table_in   dbms_tf.table_t
) return clob sql_macro is

  stmt     clob;
  col_list clob;

begin
  for colindx in table_in.column.first .. table_in.column.last loop
    col_list := col_list || ' nvl2 ( ' || table_in.column ( colindx ).description.name || ', 1, 0 ) +';
  end loop;
  
  stmt := 'select * from table_in where ' || 
           trim ( both '+' from col_list ) || 
          ' = ' || table_in.column.count;

  return stmt;
end;
/

create table t1 (
  c1 int, c2 int
);
create table t2 (
  c1 int, c2 int, c3 int
);

insert into t1 values ( 1, 1 );
insert into t1 values ( 2, null );

insert into t2 values ( 1, 1, 1 );
insert into t2 values ( 2, 2, null );
insert into t2 values ( 3, null, 3 );

select * from nn_rows ( t1 );

C1   C2   
 1    1 

select * from nn_rows ( t2 );

C1   C2   C3   
 1    1    1 

with rws as (
  select 1 x, 1 y from dual
  union all
  select 2 x, null y from dual
)
  select * from nn_rows ( rws );

X   Y   
1   1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve your issue using `UNPIVOT`.

Take this example:

```sql
WITH test_data (ID_COL, Q1, Q2, Q3) AS
(
  SELECT 1, 1, NULL, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, NULL, NULL, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, NULL, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 1, 1, 1 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT ID_COL AS TEST_CASE,
       LISTAGG(COLUMN_NAME, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME) AS NON_NULL_COLUMNS
FROM test_data UNPIVOT EXCLUDE NULLS (UNNEEDED_VALUE FOR COLUMN_NAME IN (Q1 AS 'Q1', Q2 AS 'Q2', Q3 AS 'Q3'))
GROUP BY ID_COL;
```

This gives the following results:

| TEST_CASE | NON_NULL_COLUMNS |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Q1, Q3 |
| 2 | Q3 |
| 4 | Q1, Q2, Q3 |